# Create a "managed role" in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is it possible for a bot to create a "managed role" in discord?

Looking at the [API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#create-guild-role) it seems that it is not.

The [`RoleData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/RoleCreateOptions) used in the [`.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) also does not contain the `managed` prop

```
export interface RoleData {
  name?: string;
  color?: ColorResolvable;
  hoist?: boolean;
  position?: number;
  permissions?: PermissionResolvable;
  mentionable?: boolean;
  icon?: BufferResolvable | Base64Resolvable | EmojiResolvable | null;
  unicodeEmoji?: string | null;
}
```

Tried creating a managed role using the `RoleManager`'s [`.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create)

Comment: You cannot manually create managed roles, they are meant for integrations.

Comment: @Anu6is Thanks! So you're saying that there's no way for my bot to create a role that only it can control? I'm trying to build a bot that creates roles that should be solely controlled by it, as in, the server admin cannot delete or assign users to that role. Do you know if that's possible at all?

Comment: That is not possible.